# Google reCaptcha - How to get g-recaptcha-response - without FORM TAG

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

SOLVED the problem, solution is on the bottom...
I kindly ask for improvements or changes because it's not a nice solution, it just works but not nice implemented

**PROBLEM**

I need the g-recaptcha-response data to send it to google and verify it.

```
public function check_reCaptcha()
{
    $this->data; //this variable holds the response data 

    $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha($this->secret);
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp); // $remoteIp is optional
    if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
        // return true
    } else {
        $error = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    }
}
```

To execute $recaptcha->verfiy I need $gRecaptchaResponse. The question is how do I get these informations. My reCaptcha Widget isn't in a *form* tag.

**WHAT I HAD** (must be improved with the date sent as explained in the solution)

After clicking on the register button following code will be executed

```
this.register = function () {

    var mModel = new Model();

    mModel.checkReCaptcha().done(function(data) {

        mModel.register().done(function () {
            // if register success
        }).fail(function (textStatus) {
            // if register fails
        });

    }).fail(function(textStatus) {
        // if checkReCaptcha() fails
    });
};
```

my model looks like this, the model.register isn't important here .. there I do all the registration steps, and I want to execute this after checking the reCaptcha

The checkReCaptcha function in the model looks like this

```
this.checkReCaptcha = function()
{
    var url = 'php/main.php?controller=Auth&action=check_reCaptcha';
    var data = // get cookie data

    return this.getServer().post(url, data);
};
```

**Additional Question**

Would it be possible to start this manually 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js, I read that it will be executed when form is submited, but I don't have a form.

**FIRST TRY**

My HTML. Decided to add a form tag and put the div for reCaptcha into this form.

```
<form id="form_recaptcha" action="php/getReCaptchaResponse.php" method="post">
    <div class="g-recaptcha captcha" data-sitekey="own-data-key"></div>
    <input id="form_recaptcha_submit" type="submit" hidden/>
</form>
```

I invoke a submit on the form when the user presses register

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

In my document ready I do the following

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_recaptcha', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // if I wouldn't do the preventDefault it works, but then I'm
    // redirected, which is absolutely right... my problem is that calling   
    // preventDefault, results into not loading my g-recaptcha-response 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/getReCaptchaResponse.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The getReCaptchaResponse.php is beeing called but there is no return value, so Google doesn't generate a key.

Do somebody knows how do Google starts generating a response code ?

My PHP file called in the ajax request looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    echo 'if'; // just for debug
    return $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
} else {
    echo 'else'; // just for debug
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since nobody has commented or posted any answers yet, it would be a good time to organize and cleanup your question.  Your title is asking about one thing and your two "UPDATES" are asking something else.  Simply combine and condense everything to make more sense.  In other words, there is no point to have "updates" when nobody else is involved here yet.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky I hope its clearer now to understand the question. I figured out how to solve this problem. I think its not the nicest way to solve it, but after searching today for 5 hours it's ok for the moment. Thanks for your input.

Comment: To best help this community, please post your solution below as an "answer" rather than an update inside the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I'm not happy with my solution, but it's the only one which worked till now.

HTML

```
<iframe name="recaptchaIFrame" style="display:none !important;"></iframe>
<form id="form_recaptcha" action="php/getReCaptchaResponse.php" method="post" target="recaptchaIFrame">
    <div class="g-recaptcha captcha" data-sitekey="own-data-key"></div>
    <input id="form_recaptcha_submit" type="submit" hidden/>
</form>
```

It showed up that if I target the action, when the form is submited, to an hidden iframe, I get my g-recaptcha-response data and the page won't be redirected. Exactly what I need.

FILE getReCaptchaResponse.php which is called in the form action

Now I need to return the value, I didn't manage to save this response to a hidden html tag or return it directly in the code.

My solution is to save it into a cookie and the grab it from that cookie, at the position in the code where it is needed.

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

    $name = 'reCaptchaResponse';
    $value = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $expire = 0;
    $path = '';
    $domain = '';
    $secure = false;
    $httponly = true;

    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
}
```

Now you have your g-recaptcha-response data in a cookie and you can use it then when you need it. It's recommended to delete (set to past) the cookie after you sent the data to Google for verification.

To get the content from the Cookie with javascript, take a look at this repo: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.0.3

I got the content from the cookie serverside with PHP.

Comment: You can always create your recaptcha theme. Is not that hard. And you should mark your answer as "best answer" since it answers your question.

Comment: @EliasNicolas maybe there are better solutions so I didn't mark it as "best answer", I think the recaptcha theme is another topic here it's just about the data not the design.